# jsr-303 in spring validation validate without default group

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Is it possible to enable default validation of fields without specifying group?
For example, I have the bean:

```
class User {    
  @NotEmpty
  private String name;

  @NotEmpty(groups = UserGroup.ShouldHaveSurName.class)
  private String surname;
}
```

I want the field "name" to be validated in any case - if the group not specified for @Validated annotation in the controller, or if "ShouldHaveSurName" group specified. I believe there was the configuration for this but can't find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSR-303 validation groups define a default group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358447/jsr-303-validation-groups-define-a-default-group)

Answer (score 8):

From [**JSR-303** specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/):

> **3.4. Group and group sequence**
>
> A group defines a subset of constraints. Instead of validating all
>   constraints for a given object graph, only a subset is validated. This
>   subset is defined by the the group or groups targeted. Each constraint
>   declaration defines the list of groups it belongs to. ***If no group is
>   explicitly declared, a constraint belongs to the Default group.***

So doing following in controller should suffice:

```
@Validated({UserGroup.ShouldHaveSurName.class, Default.class})
```